# The Spring application seams to have an error

Tags: java, spring, web, thymeleaf

I am new to spring and for a project in school that I need to finish next week I must create a part of a  Product Registration System. So I need to create the login, then a form to add a new product for one type of user (applicant) and then a search page and product page for another type of user (Regulator).

I found a tuto on this site :

https://o7planning.org/fr/11705/creer-une-application-de-connexion-avec-spring-boot-spring-security-jpa#a13933643

I followed it but I didn't want to use the security part because I don't really need it.

So I did almost everything I need to start, and after that I was going to create the actual pages with CSS and all, the second form etc..

Ting is it doesn't work..

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
        package com.config;

        import javax.sql.DataSource;

        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
        import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
        import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;

        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


            @Autowired
            private DataSource dataSource;

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                http.csrf().disable();

                // The pages does not require login
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll();

                // /userInfo page requires login as ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADMIN.
                // If no login, it will redirect to /login page.
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/Applicant").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_APPLICANT', 'ROLE_REGULATOR')");

                // Config for Login Form
                http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
                        // Submit URL of login page.
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
                        .loginPage("/login")//
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/userAccountInfo")//
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")//
                        .usernameParameter("username")//
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        // Config for Logout Page
                        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/");

                // Config Remember Me.
                http.authorizeRequests().and() //
                        .rememberMe().tokenRepository(this.persistentTokenRepository()) //
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(1 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 24h

            }

            @Bean
            public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
                JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
                db.setDataSource(dataSource);
                return db;
            }

        }
```

MainController.java

```
    package com.controller;

    import java.security.Principal;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    import com.entity.User;

    @Controller
    public class MainController {

        @RequestMapping(value={"/","/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String loginPage(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Login");
            return "loginPage";
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/Applicant", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String userInfo(Model model, Principal principal) {

            String userName = principal.getName();

            System.out.println("User Name: " + userName);

            model.addAttribute("userInfo", userName);

            return "loginPage";
    }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.UNEP</groupId>
        <artifactId>UNEP</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>UNEP</name>
        <description>Project Techno Web UNEP Website</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Application.properties

```
    # ===============================
    # DATABASE
    # ===============================

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/techno_web?useSSL=false
    spring.datasource.username=username
    spring.datasource.password=password
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

    # ===============================
    # JPA / HIBERNATE
    # ===============================

    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

UnepApplication.java

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UnepApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UnepApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

So this is the error I get when I run as Spring :

```
     .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

    2019-01-31 14:09:11.673  INFO 4668 --- [           main] com.UnepApplication                      : Starting UnepApplication on DESKTOP-MOLHK96 with PID 4668 (D:\Documents\Eclipse-Workspace\UNEP\target\classes started by Nicolas IMBS in D:\Documents\Eclipse-Workspace\UNEP)
    2019-01-31 14:09:11.679  INFO 4668 --- [           main] com.UnepApplication                      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2019-01-31 14:09:15.274  INFO 4668 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2019-01-31 14:09:15.576  INFO 4668 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 296ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
    2019-01-31 14:09:15.866  INFO 4668 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54d5f643] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.119  INFO 4668 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.135  INFO 4668 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.135  INFO 4668 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.140  INFO 4668 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_201/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_201/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_201/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Autre\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Users\Nicolas IMBS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Windows\System32;;.]
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.290  INFO 4668 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.290  INFO 4668 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4577 ms
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.364  WARN 4668 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.366  INFO 4668 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.428  INFO 4668 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2019-01-31 14:09:16.436 ERROR 4668 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.UnepApplication.main(UnepApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: *It doesn't work* is not a question

Answer (score 3):

The error says:

> Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Your data source is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/techno_web?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

But you have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove these and add the MySQL JDBC Driver

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: beat me by time :) , thumbs

Comment: Exactly that. The one criticism I have with Spring is that you have to read to the end of a very long error message to get to the underlying cause.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

The error is thronw because you load in `pom.xml` two dependencies for pôstgres and sql server which are usless ;

so add the mysql dependency and remove other jdbc drivers dependency (useless )

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

As this is no question i just suggest the following:

You wrote, that you dont care about the security stiff, so why you kept the WebSecurityConfig?

As you seem to be not far from the beginning, just drop the whole thing and start over. Everything  you wanna do is expressed in this tutorial -> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SpringBoot/article.html

I've completed it a few days ago. Have fun and good luck @school.

Comment: Tank you for the advice, I will maybe start over I kind of lost myself in the whole tutorial.